# Which process sent data out of my computer?

Tags: networking, process, statistical

Using vnstat, I observed a lot of uploaded data from my computer and I don't know which process sent data out of my computer. Is there a tool to get stats on how much data a process consumed during a period of time? Thank you.

Update:
Looks like the process isn't sending data anymore, I installed `nethogs` to monitor live data transfer and everything seem totally normal.

Comment: I edited the question, precising that what I'm looking for is stats on past data use of processes.

Answer (score 4):

Then nethogs command line utility will show you the network usage of every process on your system. You can install it by using

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

Then just type in "nethogs" into the terminal and as soon as the process starts to use your bandwidth it will be listed.

Comment: just what i need ,  pid+user + program + network interface and in/out and already sorted by speed !  thanx !